# In hide/show type of TOC, How To appear TOC in hided condition

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

I have a code of TOC on my website it seems to be very great for users.

But when I integrate it into my [indiantechhunter's](https://www.indiantechhunter.in) it appears in open condition i.e in show condition, I want it to be in Hided condition.

How can I do It?

The code is here ↓

```html
<html>
<head>
    ...HEAD Stuff...
    <script>
    var hideTOC = function(){
        var hideThese = document.getElementsByClassName("toc_list");
        for (var i = 0; i < hideThese.length; i++){
            hideThese[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById("showTOC").style.display = "";
    }
    var showTOC = function(){
        var showThese = document.getElementsByClassName("toc_list");
        for (var i = 0; i < showThese.length; i++){
            showThese[i].style.display = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("showTOC").style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...BODY Stuff...
    <div id="toc_container">
        <p class="toc_title">Contents [<a href='javascript:void(null)' class='toc_list' onclick='hideTOC()'>hide</a><a href='javascript:void(null)' id='showTOC' style="display:none;" onclick='showTOC()'>show</a>]</p>
        <ul class="toc_list">
            <li><a href="#First_Point_Header">1 First Point Header</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_1">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#First_Sub_Point_2">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Second_Point_Header">2 Second Point Header</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header">3 Third Point Header</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...BODY Stuff...
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show it as shown in the following photo when a user opens page containing TOC.
[image: I want this result]

Comment: You’re executing the script before the elements exist. Move your script to the bottom just above the closing body tag.